# Survey MEAN - posting id and input to controller for create with associated schemas

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, mean-stack, model-associations

I have been attempting to make a survey app in MEAN. I have two schemas, user & survey, and they are associated one to many. My problem is from the 'create' html to client controller, I want to pass the user id and input (id needed for a findOne query). I would think as part of the same 'new_survey' object. In the end, I want surveys in the user.question array. I think I'm confused a bit as I have googled/stack overflowed this for a couple days and can't seem to figure it out. And, new_survey works fine but does not associate with the user at hand. (User is grabbed from $scope.user)

html--

```
<h3>Put the question and options here:</h3>
Name: {{user}}<span></span><br><br>
Question:<input type='text' ng-model='new_survey.question'>
Option 1:<input type='text' ng-model='new_survey.opt_1'>
Option 2:<input type='text' ng-model='new_survey.opt_2'>
Option 3:<input type='text' ng-model='new_survey.opt_3'>
Option 4:<input type='text' ng-model='new_survey.opt_4'><br>

<button><a href='#/dashboard' ng-click="create(new_survey)">Add Survey</a></button>
```

client controller--

```
$scope.create = function(new_survey){
        console.log(new_survey, "new_survey into the client controller"); //
    SurveyFactory.create(new_survey, function(survey){
        //console.log(survey, "callback client controller" ); //
    getAllUsers();
    });
};
```

factory--

```
factory.create = function(info, callback){
        console.log(info, 'info in factory');
    $http.put('/surveys', info).success(function(rtnd_data){
            console.log(rtnd_data, 'create survey rtn data'); //
        callback(rtnd_data);
    }); 
};
```

routes--

```
app.put('/surveys', function (req,res){
    console.log(req.body, "req.body routes"); //
    survey.addquestion(req,res);
});
```

server controller--

```
addquestion: function(req,res){
//console.log(req.body, 'req.body'); //same w/ user obj as survey id
//console.log(req.body.id, 'req.body.id'); //survey id = whole user
var question = new Surveys({
   question: req.body.question,
   opt_1: req.body.opt_1,
   opt_2: req.body.opt_2,
   opt_3: req.body.opt_3,
   opt_4: req.body.opt_4,
   _user: req.body.id._id
});

var newQuestion = [question]; //obj in array
    console.log(newQuestion, 'newQuestion'); //is an obj, not array

var  user = req.body.id; //right! user obj
    console.log(user, 'user');

user.questions.push(newQuestion);
```

var newUser = newQuestion;
        console.log(newUser, 'newUser'); //not right
model--

```
var SurveySchema = mongoose.Schema({
question: String,
opt_1: String,
opt_2: String,
opt_3: String,
opt_4: String,
date_entered: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
_user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});

mongoose.model('Surveys', SurveySchema);

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    questions: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Surveys'}]
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Many thanks :)

The updated controller function ---

```
addquestion: function(req,res){
    //console.log(req.body, 'req.body'); //same w/ user obj as survey id
    //console.log(req.body.id, 'req.body.id'); //survey id = whole user
    var question = new Surveys({
        question: req.body.question,
            opt_1: req.body.opt_1,
            opt_2: req.body.opt_2,
            opt_3: req.body.opt_3,
            opt_4: req.body.opt_4,
            _user: req.body.id._id
            });
        //console.log(question, 'question'); //correct survey
        //console.log(req.body.id.questions, 'req.body.id.questions'); //empty array - correct inside survey
        var newQuestions = req.body.id.questions; //obj in array
            //console.log(newQuestions, 'newQuestions'); //survey in array in user
            user = req.body.id; //right! user obj
            //console.log(user, 'user');
        var newUser = newQuestions.push(question);
            console.log(newUser, 'newUser'); //not right

        User.findOne().update({_id: user._id}, newUser)
            question.save(function(err){
                if(err)
            {
              console.log("error");
            }
            else
            {
              res.send({status: "success"});
            }
          })
    },
```

server console---

```
[ { question: 'ujh',
opt_1: 'bkjhnkjhnhk',
opt_2: 'jkjbn',
opt_3: 'kjhn',
opt_4: 'kjn',
_user: 55cd4a486c73ebf02e3e4334,
_id: 55cd5c123c9d69ae41a700da,
date_entered: Thu Aug 13 2015 20:10:10 GMT-0700 (PDT) } ] 'newQuestion'
```

{ __v: 0,
  name: 'Sam',
  _id: '55cd4a486c73ebf02e3e4334',
  questions: [] } 'user'

```
[ { question: 'ujh',
    opt_1: 'bkjhnkjhnhk',
    opt_2: 'jkjbn',
    opt_3: 'kjhn',
    opt_4: 'kjn',
    _user: 55cd4a486c73ebf02e3e4334,
    _id: 55cd5c123c9d69ae41a700da,
    date_entered: Thu Aug 13 2015 20:10:10 GMT-0700 (PDT) } ] 'newUser'
```

{} 'req in show, routes'

```
[ { _id: 55ae7aaea5e270ae6494704d,
    name: 'Sam',
    __v: 0,
questions: [] },
```

{ _id: 55ae97f6a73fa44868b9d0b3,
    name: 'Sam',
    __v: 0,
    questions: [] },
  { _id: 55cd4a486c73ebf02e3e4334,
    name: 'Sam',
    __v: 0,
    questions: [] } ]

Answer (score 0):

I tried re-creating your application in my MEAN template, but I can't see your User functions, so let me know if I'm missing anything and I can edit.

First thing, I don't see where you're passing the User ID in the req.body. I would include the user object in my request in the Angular controller:

```
  $scope.create = function(new_survey){
                new_survey.id = $scope.user; //Assign the User to the request object
                console.log(new_survey, "new_survey into the client controller"); 
                $scope.Factorycreate(new_survey, function(survey){
                    //console.log(survey, "callback client controller" ); 
                    getAllUsers();
                });
            };
```

Then in your server controller, you can define the new object in an object format, to assign all the variables correctly. If you already have your whole user object, you shouldn't need to call the findOne function, but if not,  I would structure it like this:

```
var question = new Surveys({
       question: req.body.question,
       opt_1: req.body.opt_1,
       opt_2: req.body.opt_2,
       opt_3: req.body.opt_3,
       opt_4: req.body.opt_4,
       _user: req.body.id._id
   });
   //console.log(question, 'question'); //correct survey
   //console.log(req.body.id.questions, 'req.body.id.questions'); //empty array - correct inside survey
   var newQuestions = [question]; //obj in array
   //console.log(newQuestions, 'newQuestions'); //survey in array in user
  var  user = req.body.id; //right! user obj
   //console.log(user, 'user');
   newQuestions.push(question);
   var newUser = newQuestions
   console.log(newUser, 'newUser'); //not right
   User.findOne().update({_id: user._id}, newUser)
   question.save(function(err){
       if(err)
       {
           console.log("error");
       }
       else
       {
           res.send({status: "success"});
       }
```

Hope this helps, let me know what I might be missing and I can edit.

Comment: Awesome. I'll give it a run today! The user id wasn't passed from the html in this code because I deleted it as it was passing separately from the new_survey object. Not what I thought I should be doing.

Comment: I had to change the server controller a little as post was undefined from the getgo. It all seems to be going great until it gets to the 'push'. I am baffled, it does not return an object so I can't debug past that. And I think I want to keep the findOne but not sure, I think update the user I just created from the dashboard is likely best. Do you need any additional code? This is what I have...

Comment: Have you used Node-inspector? It is really awesome, it lets you debug your node side code, so that way you can see your req and res objects to see what's missing, I use it all the time. I made some edits to the server controller, I think an array needed to be added for the push.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, including when putting the object 'question' into an array. I need to push the 'question' to the user.questions array:    var newUser = user.questions.push(newQuestions); I couldn't get node-inspector to do quite what I wanted but the console.logs seem to be sufficient (hence so many of them lol). The user.questions is an empty array at the start, would that have an impact on the push?

Comment: Try removing the var from the push and just do the push on it's own. I updated the answer. As long as it's an array, the push should work successfully

Comment: Well, tried that and did some research. On a positive note, I'm getting errors but sadly, it's not pushing to user.questions as I intended.

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching to no avail. What I need to do, in fact, is somehow "push" the question *object* into the user.questions (nested) *array*. I believe I'm getting the error because you can't actually push an object. I'll keep looking in the mean time. Thanks for your help thus far.

{ question: 'ghcvgf',
  opt_1: 'jugjh',
  opt_2: undefined,
  opt_3: undefined,
  opt_4: undefined,
  _user: 55cd4a486c73ebf02e3e4334,
  _id: 55cd5594cb6784d93afe486d,
  date_entered: Thu Aug 13 2015 19:42:28 GMT-0700 (PDT) } 'question'
{ __v: 0,
  name: 'Sam',
  _id: '55cd4a486c73ebf02e3e4334',
  questions: [] } 'user'